# Ford PCM how to open

Tags: ford, repair, electronic-control-module

I have a problem with a PCM hardware VK2-C3812(8C3A-12A650-BFD). Three connectors on the "front". I get the case to separated alright but the three connectors are glued to the upper(thinner) case but the PC board is attached to the lower larger part. It looked at first like if I were to Dremel with a cutting blade I could get thru the glue but no, just more metal. Any hints as to how to open one of these? Or did Ford have them built so thay cannot be repaired? Frustrating as this particular type is very rare for the 6.8L V10 engine.
GeorgeC

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Just a guess; ECMs are sealed in many brands as there are "No user serviceable parts", meaning they're designed for one-time use whether or not they're programmable from a dealer's point of view. If Ford dealer techs determine failure, remove and replace. Diyers on the other hand are free to pry, mangle, attempt repairs and alter programming after new car warranty expires. My guess is this one is sealed, so several ways of opening are considered; heat to soften adhesive used as sealant, appropriate solvent softening sealant, and the right heat applied to soften adhesive.

Comment: Have you tried the BFH option? J/K! :o)